# What is the best way to upload multiple files in one request in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm need to simulate a web form's ability to include as many File inputs as one wishes in the FORM and have all the files arrive together in one request.

What's the prescribed method for performing said operation in AS3? 
(I'm using AIR, but I doubt that makes any difference).

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, I hate answering my own questions, but I found this solution: http://blog.mikestead.me/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-request-in-flash/
and it works REALLY nicely and is entirely code complete, I had to do virtually no noodling at all.
The only thing the docs fail to detail (which I'll add here) is that on the server side (specifically in PHP) the files arrive hash indexed by the variable name you set. So when you do

```
urlVariables["image1"] = new URLFileVariable(filePicker.data, filePicker.name); //this adds your file to the request in flash
```

Then on the PHP side you will find that file in

```
$_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"];
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it is a decent alternate to the class I mention.  FWIW, I went through the source for this class and it is also doing a multipart/form-data request.  It is does look a bit simpler to use, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a multipart form upload.  I think the class I used is at http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=139, but I would have to double check when I get to the office.

EDIT:  Yes, the link above is correct.  This particular class makes file uploads and `multipart/form-data` pretty much a no brainer in AS3.

Comment: that's a good answer, but I found an even more complete one... I hate answering my own questions, but in this case, I think I do have the better answer. Gave you a 1 up though! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods: zipping, or tracking multiple uploads.

If you want to zip the files, here is a walk-through [on how to go about zipping, uploading, and unzipping from AIR](http://justinjmoses.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/air-multiple-file-uploads-drag-n-drop-to-client-zip-to-server-upload-and-unzip/).

If you want to upload multiple files, what you need to do is have an Array of booleans or a counter that keeps track of how many uploads were started. Then on an an event capturing upload completion, the booleans need to be turned from `false` to `true` or another counter needs to count the completions. Once all booleans are true or the two counters values match, you know all the files have been uploaded.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
fileCount= 0
fileUploadCompleteCount = 0

foreach(file in fileArray)
    fileCount++
    file.listenForUploadComplete(uploadComplete)

function uploadComplete()
    fileUploadCompleteCount++
    checkUploadProgress()

function checkUploadProgress()
    if(fileUploadCompleteCount == fileCount)
        // all files have been uploaded
```

Comment: no no... I don't want to do multiple uploads, I want to do 1 upload, filled with multiple files and other parameters. I've found the answer... I'll post it shortly.